# recursive toString in Queue Linked List in Java

Tags: java, list, recursion, linked-list, queue

I need to implement a toString() recursive method for a linked list Queue. I know my toString method worked fine on a linked list implementation I did last week, so something is wrong with how I'm handling the Queue aspect of it.

toString method for my QueueList:

```
public String toString() 
{ 

    if (front.info == null)
    {
        System.out.println("Error, queue is empty");
        return "";
    }
    if (front.link  == null) //base case: if this is last element in stack
    {

        return  (" \"" + front.info + "\" , ");
    } 
    else //normal recursive function
    {
        return  (" \"" + front.info + "\" , " + front.link.toString());

    }   

}
```

and my constructors and such for QueueList:

```
public class QueueNode 
{
    E info;
    QueueNode link;
}

private QueueNode front;//first element to be placed into queue
private QueueNode rear;//last element to be placed into queue
private int NoE;//counter for number of elements in queue
public QueueList() 
{ 
    front = null;
    rear = null;
    NoE = 0;
}
```

I tried to see what was going on in it using this test:

```
public boolean test() { 
    QueueList<String> q = new QueueList<String>();

    q.enqueue("The Godfather");
    q.enqueue("Casino");
    q.enqueue("Goodfellas");
    String r = q.toString();
    q.PrettyPrint();
```

with the output

```
IN -> [ "The Godfather" , QueueList$QueueNode@a3901c6] -> OUT.
```

I realize this is because I'm telling saying `front.link.toString()` in the recursive part of the `toString` method, but even if I change it to `front.link.info.toString()`, my output is

```
IN -> [ "The Godfather" , Casino] -> OUT.
```

It may be possibly something to do with with my enqueue and dequeue methods then, which are as follows:

```
public void enqueue(E element) 
{ 

        QueueNode newNode = new QueueNode();//creates new Node to hold element
        newNode.info = element;//set info of new Node to element
        newNode.link = null;//make link null since it's at back of list
        if (rear == null)//checks if queue is empty
        {
            front = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            rear.link = newNode;//sets second to last node's link to newNode
        }
        rear = newNode;//makes newNode the new last link
        NoE++;//increase counter

}
public E dequeue() throws InvalidOperationException 
{
    if (front == null)//sanitize code
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("There is nothing in the queue.");
    }
    E element = front.info;//creates an element file that takes the info in front of queue
    front = front.link;//makes second-to-front element new front
    if (front == null)//if this emptied the queue, make sure rear is also empty
    {
        rear = null;
    }
    NoE--;//reduce counter
    return element;
}
```

Please help me out if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to make `toString` recursive, and in fact it is *incorrect* to do so. Your data structure is not recursive (i.e. a tree) but linear.

If your list contained, say, 1 million items, you would quickly run out of stack space (StackOverflow, literally).

Use a loop instead.

EDIT: If you are *required* do to this recursively, then the issue is that the recursive method must be `QueueNode#toStringRecursive()`, not `Queue#toString()`.  The method `Queue#toString()` allocates a buffer and provides it to a special `toStringRecursive()` method on `QueueNode` which does the recursion.  `QueueNode#toString()` must be responsible only for its own node contents.

Method `Queue#toString()`

```
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    if (front == null)
        // queue is empty
    else
        front.toStringRecursive(buf);
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Method `QueueNode#toStringRecursive()`

```
public void toStringRecursive(StringBuilder buf)
{
    buf.append(this.toString());
    if (this.link != null)
        this.toStringRecursive(buf);
}
```

where `QueueNode.toString()` is responsible only for stringifying one node (itself).

Note that this is *one* way to do it.  It would be possible to write this as a recursive method on `Queue` as well, but it could not be called `toString()`. `Queue#toString()` would set up the initial conditions and then invoke the recursion.

Comment: I felt similarly, and wrote it iteratively, and when I went in to see my professor about another problem with the assignment, she said I may lose points if I didn't write it recursively. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Sorry, but your professor is mistaken.  This is not a recursive problem and your intuition was correct.  I've updated my answer

Comment: I agree with you 100%. My code finally works, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please click the checkmark next to the vote counter to mark it 'accepted'.